# Set IMG as cover to its parent container

Tags: html, css, image, autoresize, resize-image

I'd like to make each IMG element behave as **background-size:cover** behaves for background images. Basically resize the IMG to perfectly fit its container without diforming it.

The IMG's container must stay 100x100px.
The HTML must stay as it is. Only the CSS can be modified.

The images are random and have different formats: landscape|portrait|square.

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sdf0anq4/

```
<div class="images">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <img src="http://crispme.com/wp-content/uploads/33110.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <img src="https://greatkidpix.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/teenage-portrait.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>

.images > a {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.images > a > img {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

If it really can't be done with CSS I'd like to see a simple jQuery solution.

Answer (score 2):

#### UPDATE

Modern way to achieve this is by using `object-fit: cover`

```css
.images {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

img {
  border: 1px solid green;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/300" />
  </a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/600" />
  </a>
</div>
```

#### OLD Answer

Keeping your **HTML** as you asked just making a few changes in **CSS** here:

```
.images > a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top; /* just for demo purposes */
  width: 100px;
 /*removed height and overflow */
}

.images img {
  max-width: 100%; /* changed min-width to max-width */
  width: auto; /* new */
  border-radius: 100%; /* new */
  border: 1px solid red; /* just for demo purposes */
  /*removed min-height and height */
}
```

You can see the full result in the snippet below

```css
.images {
    border:1px solid blue
}

.images > a {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:100px;
}
.images img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width:auto;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">
    <img src="http://crispme.com/wp-content/uploads/33110.jpg" />
  </a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">
    <img src="https://greatkidpix.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/teenage-portrait.jpg" />
  </a>

</div>
```

##EDIT

updated answer with **jQuery**:

```js
$('img').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass(this.width > this.height ? 'landscape' : 'portrait');
});
```

```css
.images {
    border:1px solid blue
}

.images > a {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    border:1px solid green;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
.images .portrait {
    max-width:100%;
}
.images .landscape {
    max-height:100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="images">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <img src="http://crispme.com/wp-content/uploads/33110.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <img src="https://greatkidpix.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/teenage-portrait.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I have forgot to mentions that the <a> should remain square. Thanks

Comment: so you want the `a`square but `img` with `radius 100%`?

Comment: see updated answer, and let me know if this what you are looking for.. I'm not fully understanding what you are trying to achieve

Comment: the <a> should have radius 100%, not the image. the image should behave similar to background-size:cover(*it fits the container regardless of its size) or similar to http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/.

Comment: The <a> should stay 100x100px, to result in a perfect rounded image.

Comment: now I'm confused.. you say: "I have forgot to mentions that the <a> should remain square.", now you say you want your `a` to be rounded? So how do we stay?

Comment: should look as in my example, but the IMGs should not be distorted. When I said square I was reffering to be 100x100px

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72585/discussion-between-dippas-and-george).